# How to find Semantic Relationship between two synsets in WordNet

Tags: python, perl, similarity, wordnet

I am working with WordNet 3.0. 
I would like to know how could i find semantic relation between two synsets in WordNet hierarchy.
As in, given two words as input i want to find the relationship between them i.e. whether they are synonyms, hyponym-hypernym etc.

Is there a python or perl module to achieve this?

Comment: Which library are you using? For which human language?

Answer (score 5):

NLTK is the most used NLP library for Python.
The described operation would be something like:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

house = wordnet.synset('house.n.01')
station = wordnet.synset('station.n.01')
```

then you can use the method of the class [Synset](https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset-class.html) this way:

```
taxonomy_distance = house.shortest_path_distance(station)
```

to found whether they are synonyms:

```
common_lemmas = len(set(house.lemma_names).intersection(set(station.lemma_names)))
```

which will return the number of common lemmas in the two sets.

You could also use a graph database like Neo4j to load the wordnet dataset and look for the shortest path between their nodes, a problem discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/lzS8aNrUq1U).

Answer (score 2):

Using Python NLTK (version >= 3.7):

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> 
>>> synset1 = wn.synset('adornment.n.01')
>>> synset2 = wn.synset('jewelry.n.01')
>>> 
>>> synset1.lowest_common_hypernyms(synset2)
[Synset('adornment.n.01')]
>>> 
>>> synset1.hyponyms()
[Synset('frill.n.03'), Synset('rosette.n.01'), Synset('frontlet.n.01'), Synset('cordon.n.03'), Synset('fob.n.02'), Synset('beauty_spot.n.01'), Synset('sequin.n.01'), Synset('war_paint.n.01'), Synset('boutonniere.n.01'), Synset('trimming.n.02'), Synset('pendant.n.01'), Synset('pompon.n.01'), Synset('band.n.04'), Synset('bangle.n.02'), Synset('jewelry.n.01'), Synset('epaulet.n.01'), Synset('circlet.n.02'), Synset('frog.n.03'), Synset('tassel.n.01'), Synset('plume.n.02'), Synset('pectoral.n.02')]
>>> synset2.hypernyms()
[Synset('adornment.n.01')]
```

To get synonyms:

```
>>> def lemmas_in_all_synsets(keyword):
...     lemmas=[]
...     for synset in wn.synsets(keyword):
...         for lemma in synset.lemmas():
...             lemmas.append(lemma)
...     return lemmas
...
>>> lemmas_in_all_synsets('station')
[Lemma('station.n.01.station'), Lemma('place.n.10.place'), Lemma('place.n.10.sta
tion'), Lemma('station.n.03.station'), Lemma('post.n.01.post'), Lemma('post.n.01
.station'), Lemma('station.n.05.station'), Lemma('station.v.01.station'), Lemma(
'station.v.01.post'), Lemma('station.v.01.send'), Lemma('station.v.01.place')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def synonyms(x):
    from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
    synonyms_x = []
    for syn in wn.synsets(x):
        for l in syn.lemmas():
            synonyms_x.append(l.name())
    #to remove duplicates from the list
    synonyms_x = list(dict.fromkeys(synonyms_x)) 
    return synonyms_x
```